# What "upside down relative to each other" means?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

> Sheet A is generally placed on sheet B, but sheet A can be placed under sheet B.

I am trying to rewrite the sentence above I created by using "upside down". My examples are as follows:

> 1. ..., but they can be placed upside down.
> 2. ..., but they can be placed upside down **relative to each other**.

I am afraid that the first sentence may be interpreted that each sheet is turned upside down without change in their relative position, so I created the second sentence. Does the second sentence express what I want to say?

Comment: I looked up some dictionaries and found the following definition at the Merriam-Webster:  " in such a way that the upper and the lower parts are reversed in position" .  Therefore, it may seem that the first sentence is correct.

Comment: Very possibly correct, but very easy to misunderstand. If you want to explain something, you have to be more than correct.

Answer (score -1):

Since the concept you are going for is fundamentally about which one is on top and which one is on the bottom, I think you should use words that have those explicit meanings, (e.g above, under, top, bottom, upper, on, beneath, etc.)

The expression "upside down" really describes the orientation of one object (not the relative position of two objects), and in 3-dimensional space, even the concept of "upside down" is easy to misinterpret without extra clarification.

So I don't advise using "upside down" in this circumstance. I think your very first sentence is about as clear as you are going to get.